# Alternative for Null Coalescing Operator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, null-coalescing-operator

With Java, to safely access a deep nested reference like
`a.b.c.d.e`, we'd usually have to specify null checks at each level or wrap in `Optional`s and use `orElse()`. (Unlike with languages like Kotlin/C# where `a?.b?.c?.d?.e` or similar works.

I was wondering if the following helper method could be a reasonable alternative:

```
public <T> T valueOrNull(Supplier<T> expression) {
    try {
        return expression.get();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This can then be used safely with `value = valueOrNull(() -> a.b.c.d.e)`.

Note: I understand that catching `NullPointerException`s is usually frowned upon because of performance reasons and more, but was wondering if the usage here would be a reasonable exception.

Comment: Catching of `NullPointerExceptions` has little to do with performance and a lot to do with general code quality.

Comment: One might even argue that having to write `a.b.c.d.e` (or `a?.b?.c?.d?.e`) already indicates dubious design (not that I wouldn't welcome such an operator, but I tend to get less nesting than that).

Comment: @Kayaman I mentioned performance because using exceptions for control flow is generally much slower than simple branching. And code quality wouldn't be that much of an issue if this isolated to just this method. Regarding your second comment, this may be true in most cases, but consider a POJO representing an XML schema, where you use JAXB or some-such for conversions. It's valid to have to access a deeply nested xml node where you can't be certain of the validity of the path.

Comment: This is significantly less flexible than using `Optional`, and I don't think the slightly reduced verbosity is worth introducing such a utility.

Comment: @Hulk I disagree on both points. I could imagine that this would be a useful tool when for example refactoring legacy code with deeply nested if clauses. Also, this isn't offered as an alternative to `Optional`, but as an addition.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a function that takes a value and a getter to transform it, like so

```
public static <T1, T2> T1 coalesce(T2 value, Function<T2,T1> f1){
    return f1.apply(value);
}
```

which you would then call like so `coalesce(value, Clazz::getA)`.

For every step further in your chain, you need an additional Function in your coalesce function, like so

```
public static <T1, T2, T3> T1 coalesce(T3 value, Function<T3,T2> f1, Function<T2,T1> f2){
    T2 t2 = f1.apply(value);
    if(t2 == null)
        return null;    
    return f2.apply(t2);
}
```

for a depth of two, and

```
public static <T1, T2, T3, T4> T1 coalesce(T4 value, Function<T4,T3> f1, Function<T3,T2> f2, Function<T2,T1> f3){
    T3 t3 = f1.apply(value);
    if(t3 == null)
        return null;
    T2 t2 = f2.apply(t3);
    if(t2 == null)
        return null;
    return f3.apply(t2);
}
```

for a depth of three and so on for further depths.

Example code:

```
    A test1 = new A(null);
    A test2 = new A(new B(null));
    A test3 = new A(new B(new C(null)));
    A test4 = new A(new B(new C("1234")));

    System.out.println(coalesce(test1, A::getB, B::getC, C::getS));
    System.out.println(coalesce(test2, A::getB, B::getC, C::getS));
    System.out.println(coalesce(test3, A::getB, B::getC, C::getS));
    System.out.println(coalesce(test4, A::getB, B::getC, C::getS));

    System.out.println(coalesce(test2, A::getB));
    System.out.println(coalesce(test3, A::getB, B::getC));
```

A is a class with a member of class B, B is a class with a member of class C, C is a class with a member of class String, with appropriate getters. Output is as expected:

```
null
null
null
1234    
B@776ec8df
C@41629346
```

Nulls for the first three cases, where the string in C is null, the fourth has the value of the string, and fifth and sixth return objects of type B and C respectivelly.

I don't see a way to make the code much shorter unfortunately.

Comment: The OP's solution is definitely more flexible and simpler.

Comment: OP's solution also uses exceptions for control flow and silently catches exceptions. I simply added another way of doing it in java 8.

Comment: "Silently" catching the exception is a feature rather than a negative issue here.

Comment: Except if the NPE occurs from something other than the method call on a null pointer. If any of the inner methods throws a legitimate NPE, this may cause problems.

Comment: True, but presumably the inner methods are simple getters. Sure, you could abuse the construct, but there's no way to prevent people from writing bad, ugly or harmful code.

Comment: @JureKolenko, interesting approach, but I see some similarities between your solution and `Optional.map()`, using which the equivalent would be `value = Optional.ofNullable(a).map(A::getB).map(B::getC).map(C::getD).map(D::getE).orElse(null)`, which I'd argue is more flexible (yet more verbose than my original solution).

Comment: It is definitely similar, although slightly less verbose.